# Trying to cast a string to an int in SQL Server to make it show something like Cust-0001 rather than just the customer id being 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my question is really what it says in the title. I am looking to make the customer ID column look like `CUST-0001`, rather than just keeping it simply 1 or 01.

I know you have to make a separate `id` column to have the number and I know you use the cast function but I am not sure of the syntax works in T-SQL. It will also act as a primary key for the table so I know it will be `identity(1,1)` for incrementing it by 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried researching it and I'm doing it to try and gain an extra mark or two and make sure my data looks neat for my own sake haha

Answer (score 0):

I don't really advise you to do this; just get used to the numeric ids.  That is the best way to store each row for indexing and foreign key references.

But if you really want to, start with an `identity` column that has the customer id.  Then define a computed column:

```
alter table t add customerId_str as ('CUST-' + right(replace('0', 6) + cast(CustomerId as varchar(255)), 6));
```

I gave the customer id as six digits rather than 4.